# Service of Type LoadBalancer on AKS

Tags: azure, ip, kubernetes, azure-load-balancer

I am using AKS and when I create a service of type LoadBalancer, it creates a service and allocates and IP but the following requests to create services of type loadbalancer the IP does not get allocated and it shows `<pending>` state forever

I verified that the quotas for public IP are witin range. Is this a limitation that I am hitting? How should I go abot debugging this?

This is a relevant link 
https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/issues/737

I see this when I descibe the service

```
 Warning  CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  18s (x5 over 1m)  service-controller  Error creating load balancer (will retry): Failed to create load balancer for service kubernetestypo32/hello-world-serviceypo32: network.LoadBalancersClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="LoadBalancerFrontendIPConfigurationCountLimitReached" Message="Basicsku load balancer /subscriptions/c28f7a55-03f7-41fb-b96b-011eff3ce42e/resourceGroups/MC_spalshikResourceGroup_spalshikK8sCluster_eastus/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/kubernetes cannot have more than 10 FrontendIPConfigurations." Details=[]
```

Comment: is this your first publicIp on this load balancer? well, do you have less than 10 public IPs attached to this lb?

Comment: This is the only service on the cluster , behind it are three pods. So I am guessing there is just one IP in play?

Comment: can you do a `kubectl describe services service name`?

Comment: ok, something funky going on with your loadbalancer, can you show frontend configurations from your load balancer, or do you see something funky by looking at them? you can look at the portal

Comment: Looking at it, where does it get the 10 configurations from?

Comment: how many are there? try changing load balancer tier?

Comment: there is just one service I created in the cluster. Shouldnt it just expose one  IP, where is it getting those 10 frontend IPs from?

Comment: did you examine frontend configurations? not just ip addresses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163820/discussion-between-user-mda-and-4c74356b41).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in this case the problem was in a stale ip addresses in the load balancer configurations. They need to be removed.

proper way of doing that - removing stale kubernetes services